# Cat Chewing At Nails/Toes & Heavy Digging

Tags: cats, grooming, allergies, scratching

My boyfriend's cat has had this issue for over a year and the vet cannot figure it out. (Hundreds of dollars wasted.)

He won't stop grooming until he bleeds, ripping out fur and itching all around. Worst at the rear. Then there's him practically tearing out his claws, grabbing onto them with his teeth and jerking. He does the same to his paw pads.

We've changed everything: food, litter, food dishes. Nothing seems to work
I checked one of the claw shells he tore out, and there are some thick black clumps on the inside. (May be dried blood though.)

He's fully indoor!

EDIT: We've changed his food to sensitive stomach & then tried sensitive skin when he started to throw it up towards the second bag (both from vet approved websites.) Steroid shots worked for a week and a half, and then we tried these steroid pills (less than effective.) Changed his litter to organic, plastic dishes to metal ones.

This didn't seem to start happening until he got his first case of fleas (they're long gone now.)

Comment: Hi Chelsea, if you can go into detail about everything you've tried, then someone may be able to provide a new suggestion. I expect your vet has already talked to you at length about allergic disease, so unless we know what has been done, what food trials that have been performed, etc. it is going to be difficult to provide any advice. What tests have been done? Any treatments tried..steroids, antibiotics? Even so it will be difficult for random internet people to help, sounds like your cat may be one who needs to be refered to a dermatologist.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Has your vet eliminated http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/skin/c_ct_flea_bite_hypersensitivity ?

Comment: are you still treating regularly for fleas with something like revolution? if not, there still may be a couple that you haven't seen.  Also, are you seeing a general vet or a specialist (dermatology)?